# Calculated Column vs. Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, calculated-column

This is my second question in as many days. I was successful with my first question.  So here goes:
I set up a ACR/Project Number Assignment log which auto-generates a customized, sequential number.

I have 2 calculated columns, the first creates the unique number upon creating a new log entry.  The second is the "Closed Date" column which adds the current date or N/A dependent on the status of the entry (Open, Closed or Canceled).  Here's the rub, all of the assigned numbers reflect "000" where a sequential number should appear. Only, when I go into list settings, open the corresponding list and refresh the page does the seq. number display.

Obviously , a delay, glitch or lag in the formula.  So, I think a workflow is the better way to go. It will also allow for an email to go to the requestor.

1st cal. col. formula:

```
=IF(Category="Project File","PF-IS-"&Location&TEXT(Created,"-yy")
&CONCATENATE  ("-",REPT("0",MAX(0,3-LEN(ID))),ID),IF(Category="Change 
Control","CC-IS-"&Location&TEXT(Created,"-yy")&CONCATENATE("-",REPT("0",MAX
(0,3-LEN(ID))),ID)))
```

2nd cal. col. formula:

```
=IF([Project Status]="Closed",(Created),IF([Project Status]="Canceled", 
(Created),IF([Project Status]="Open","N/A")))
```

Help.   Please and thank you!

Comment: So what's your question bro? do you need to know the preferred one

Comment: Will the workflow provide the instant sequential number?

Comment: Or can I modify the formula to provide the correct sequential number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In your formula,** the issue would be in the **ID** field that will **not** be calculated until the formula is changed again in calculated column field settings.

> Check the full list of **[supported and unsupported fields in the SharePoint Calculated Column Formula.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)**

---

**In your scenario**, the available workaround is using

- the workflow instead of the calculated column,
- If you have a good knowledge of development, try to use Event Receiver instead.
- Build your formula using JSOM

**Check the details steps and other workarounds at**

- [Use SharePoint ID Field in Calculated Column.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/id-field-in-calaulated-column-sharepoint/)
- [Auto Serial Number in SharePoint New Form using JSOM.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/auto-serial-number-new-form-sharepoint/)
- [Using Lookup Field in Calculated Column SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/lookup-field-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)